# HtmlAgilityPack - ensure CanOverlap and Closed at same time

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

How can I define that `HtmlNode.ElementsFlags["div"]` can `CanOverlap` and must be `Closed` at same time?

**I have this HTML (right struture):**

```
<p>
    <div>
        <b>text:</b> 
        <img alt="" src="#" style="BORDER: 0px solid; ">
    </div>
    <div>
        <b>text:</b> 
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <p>text</p>
    </div>
</p>
```

And I need to ensure all tags are correctly openned and closed and I'm using `HtmlAgilityPack` to do that. But `HtmlAgilityPack` is changing my `HTML` because it isn't assuming tags `CanOverlap`.

**HTML returned by HtmlAgilityPack (wrong struture):**

```
<p>
   <div>
      <b>text:</b>
      <img alt="" src="#" style="BORDER: 0px solid; " />
   </div>
   <div />
   <b>text:</b>
   <div />
   <div>
        <p>
            text
        </p>
   </div>
</p>
```

How can I solve this? How can I tell `HtmlAgilityPack` tags `CanOverlap` and ensure tags be `Closed`?

**C# code**

```
if (!HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.ContainsKey("p"))
    HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Add("p", HtmlElementFlag.Closed);
else
    HtmlNode.ElementsFlags["p"] = HtmlElementFlag.Closed;

if (!HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.ContainsKey("span"))
    HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Add("span", HtmlElementFlag.Closed);
else
    HtmlNode.ElementsFlags["span"] = HtmlElementFlag.Closed;

if (!HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.ContainsKey("div"))
    HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Add("div", HtmlElementFlag.Closed);
else
    HtmlNode.ElementsFlags["div"] = HtmlElementFlag.Closed;

var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
htmlDoc.OptionWriteEmptyNodes = true;
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(myHtml);

var htmlError = htmlDoc.ParseErrors.SafeAny();

if (!htmlError)
    myHtml = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! We can say `HtmlNode.ElementsFlags` should be `Closed` and `CanOverlap`, like this:

```
if (!HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.ContainsKey("div"))
    HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Add("div", HtmlElementFlag.CanOverlap & HtmlElementFlag.Closed);
else
    HtmlNode.ElementsFlags["div"] = HtmlElementFlag.CanOverlap & HtmlElementFlag.Closed;
```